# Generating the Django route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

Tell me, please, why the route is not generated correctly?

viewSet:

```
class MyViewSet(BaseViewSet, CreateModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post']

    queryset = User.objects

    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)


    @detail_route(methods=['get'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated], url_name='my')
    def my(self, request, version, pk=None):
        serializer = MyInfoSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls:

```
users_router = DefaultRouter()
users_router.register(r'users', MyViewSet)
```

When you try to navigate to the specified address (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/users/my/), page 404 appears. Routes are formed like:

```
^api/ ^(?P<version>(v1))/ ^ ^users/$ [name='user-list']
^api/ ^(?P<version>(v1))/ ^ ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-list']
^api/ ^(?P<version>(v1))/ ^ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/my/$ [name='user-my']
^api/ ^(?P<version>(v1))/ ^ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/my\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-my']
```

Comment: Your URL is ...users/<pk>/my/, not ...users/my/.

Comment: I see it. How to fix it?